# Uncaught TypeError: require.ensure is not a function at Object.getComponent (ECMASCRIPT)

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, atmosphere

Am porting over my meteor project to use ecmascript instead of using webpack / babel. Also upgrading my meteor (from 1.4 to 1.7) and react (from 15.3.2 to 16.8.6) too.

> routes.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function (injectDeps, {Store, Routes}) {
  const route = {
    path: 'tickets',
    onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
      if (!Meteor.userId() || !Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'staff', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP)) {
        replace('/login');
      }
    },
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        Store.injectReducer('tickets', require('./reducers'));
        cb(null, require('./containers/list.js'));
      }, 'tickets');
    },
    childRoutes: [
      {
        path: ':_id',
        getComponent(nextState, cb) {
          require.ensure([], (require) => {
            Store.injectReducer('tickets', require('./reducers'));
            cb(null, require('./containers/view.js'));
          }, 'tickets.view');
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  Routes.injectChildRoute(route);
}
```

> Got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require.ensure is not a function
    at Object.getComponent (routes.jsx:20)
    at getComponentsForRoute (modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:38035)
    at modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:38053
    at modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:37842
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at mapAsync (modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:37841)
    at getComponents (modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:38052)
    at finishEnterHooks (modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:37263)
    at next (modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:37810)
    at loopAsync (modules.js?hash=d04d5856a2fe2fa5c3dc6837e85d41adc321ecb2:37814
```

Any suggestion how to port this?

Comment: Is there a specific technical reason, why you not update to 1.9?

Comment: Not really.  However am more concern about breaking changes.  Thus not planned to skip too many version.

Comment: FYI, still using react-router v3 .  No plan to go for mass changes of react-router v4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it was done to get rid of require.ensure:

**routes.jsx** (final)

```
{
    path: 'config',
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        import('./containers/config').then(mod => {
            Store.injectReducer('config', require('./reducers/config').default);
            cb(null, mod.default);
        });
    }
}
```

NOTE:
1) This is how the to migrate from `require.ensure` (used by webpack) to without relying on webpack (which was my case as am fully using Meteor Atmosphere to run)
2) `mod` and `require(...).xxx` had changed to `mod.default` and `require(...).default` if `reducer` function is exported as `export default`, otherwise said `reducer` will not be called.